# How to use Google tags in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I'm on Nuxt.js 2.13 and I want to use Google tags in my project.

But there are several things that are not clear to me!

First: there are two packages by pi0 in Nuxt.js community, [@nuxtjs/gtm](https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module) and [@nuxtjs/google-gtag](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-gtag-module). Which one should I use?

Second: How can I use `dataLayer.push({'varName':'value'})` with these packages? As in their documentation they only instructed about `push('event')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the first point:

- **[google-gtag-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-gtag-module)** is the **deprecated v1**
- **[gtm-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module)** is the **new v2**

As explained in the [release notes](https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module/releases/tag/v2.0.0):

> This is a major rewrite of @nuxtjs/google-tag-manager after 3 years of contributions and feedback from users.

---

About the second point, you have to use the `$gtm.push` method to make your push event or data.

For example, in your `pages/index.vue` file:

```js
<script>
export default {
  middleware ({ $gtm }) {
    $gtm.push({ 'varName': 'value' })
  }
}
</script>
```

See another full example with configuration at *https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module/tree/master/example*.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but, the depricated version of `@Nuxt/gtm` is this package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager` and `https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-gtag-module` is still in Nuxt community and not depricated!

Comment: that's exactly what I explained