# What is the difference between @nuxtjs/google-gtag @nuxtjs/gtm @nuxtjs/google-analytics and vue-gtag, what to use for GA4?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

Newbie to this whole analytics thing and am finding this very confusing

I wanted to use Google Analytics 4 in my nuxt ssr webapp and am feeling overwhelmed with the number of options

[Quick issue on nuxtjs/google-analytics says it does not support GA4 and is asking me to use nuxt/gtm](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs)

[stackoverflow answer on the same question says use vue-gtag](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs)

[Google's documentation says it covers analytics ads etc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs)

nuxt/google-gtag seems to be another library apart from vue-gtag and nuxt/gtm

what am I even supposed to use?
I just want to integrate Google Analytics 4 on my nuxt.js SSR app

Comment: This one may maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68504060/8816585

Comment: This issue can also help, here you can find the difference between the different modules / libraries, and what you should use according to your needs.
https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module/issues/82

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Create a GA account and a GA4 property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153#zippy=%2Cfind-your-g--id-for-any-platform-that-accepts-a-g--id) if you have not already. Keep a note of your Measurement Id (the "G-" Id). The same page can help you to find the id.
2. Use [nuxtjs/google-gtag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-gtag). Page includes setup help.
3. When passing the config in your code, use this format:

```js
 // example config
 'google-gtag':{
   id: 'G-XXXXXXXX',  // your measurement id
   ... // rest of the config
  }
```

Just to compare, for Universal Analytics (the previous version of GA), the Id would look like `UA-XXXX-XX`, instead of `G-XXXXXXXX`. Learn more with [Google Analytics 4 properties tag and instrumentation guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/tag-guide).

Comment: This link says that the google-gtag is deprecated, instead gtm is the new one. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752819/how-to-use-google-tags-in-nuxt-js